# Why isn't this background image being displayed when using a bootstrap template for it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a asp.net application, where I wanted to use a premade bootstrap template for my frontend. I found [this one](https://startbootstrap.com/theme/clean-blog).
The original site from the template looks really nice with a background like this:

[image]

I copied all the css into my css folder, and also took the html and cut some parts of it out such that I could just render my own content in it.
My `_layout.cshtml` that should be a scaffolding for other html files looks now like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="post.html">Sample Post</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Header-->
        <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('../../wwwroot/assets/home-bg.jpg')">
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="site-heading">
                            <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                            <span class="subheading">A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>

        <footer class="border-top">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="#!">
                                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                        <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fab fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="small text-center text-muted fst-italic">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2021</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as I understand, the central line for displaying the background image is this one:

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('../../wwwroot/assets/home-bg.jpg')">
```

Where we set the image as our background.

The problem is though, that the site I get, looks like this:
[image]

Instead of having the nice image as a background, I just get grey. I would like for the image to be displayed.
How do I get the image shown in the background, just like in the source i have linked?

**EDIT:**

I now looked in the dev tool, where I found it:

[image]

But clicking the image gets me `This localhost page can’t be found`.

So it might look like the given path is bad. This is a little bit strange to me, since my IDE actually suggested the entire current path to me.

What should I do with my path such that the image can be found?

Comment: If you look up the image in developer toolbar, is it loaded?

Comment: it looks as if the image gets loaded, but if I click the link to it in the dev tool, then it goes to`https://localhost:5001/wwwroot/assets/home-bg.jpg` and shows me `This localhost page can’t be found`. This is strange to me, since my ide actually suggested me the path

Comment: Just added an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your mentioned path (../../wwwroot/assets/home-bg.jpg) correct? because image won't be rendered if path is incorrect, and the background color becomes grey because of the classname mentioned.

Comment: the path should be correct. My ide suggested it for me

Answer (score 0):

i after trying the path `../../wwwroot/assets/home-bg.jpg` I then tried to assume that my application by default would be looking in the wwwroot directory. So I tried the path `assets/home-bg.jpg`.

My IDE (rider) shows red lines, and complains about it. But it works